# Persisting UIBezierPaths in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw multiple UIBezierPaths on a custom view, with the ability to manipulate them individually.

path and the NSMutableArray to store the paths are instance variables declared like:

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView {  
    UIBezierPath *path;  
    NSMutableArray *paths; // this is initialized in the init method  
}
```

The path is initialized in touchesBegan as follows:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];  
    [path moveToPoint:[touch locationInView:self];  
}
```

It is moved in the touchesMoved method as follows:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    [path addLineToPath:[touch locationInView:self]];  
    [self setsNeedsDisplay];  
}
```

And I want to store it in the NSMutableArray in touchesEnded:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    [path closePath];  
    [paths addObject:path];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];  
}
```

The problem is, after I draw one uibezierpath, and begin to draw one after that, the one i drew first disappears. I'm not sure why this is happening. Thanks in advance!

Note: I know a possible solution is storing all the points of each uibezierpath in a NSMutableArray and redrawing it everytime drawRect is called, but I feel like that is an inefficient implementation.

Comment: multi-touch will break this implementation. and we need to see your draw function

Comment: You might want to see [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a global instance  `path` . Instead of using a global instance add your path object to mutable array and get wherever you want.

Try replacing your code something like this.

```
   @interface MyCustomView : UIView {  
        NSMutableArray *paths; // this is initialized in the init method  
    }
```

The path is initialized in `touchesBegan` as follows:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];  
    [path moveToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]; 
    [paths addObject:path]; 
}
```

It is moved in the `touchesMoved` method as follows:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    UIBezierPath *path = [paths lastObject];
    [path addLineToPath:[touch locationInView:self]];  
    [self setsNeedsDisplay];  
}
```

And I want to store it in the `NSMutableArray` in `touchesEnded`:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    UIBezierPath *path = [paths lastObject];
    [path closePath];  
    [self setNeedsDisplay];  
}
```

Comment: `path` isn't global, it's an instance variable. And the way he's doing it makes sense as this way only complete paths end up in the array, while with your modification you have to remember that the last path _could_ still be unfinished.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did exactly what you did by making the path a local method variable and drew ALL the uibezierpaths as DarkDust said and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show you `drawRect:` method, but be aware that in your `drawRect:`, you need to draw *all* paths that you want displayed. Every time `drawRect:` is entered, everything you were drawing before is cleared and has to be drawn again, so just drawing the new one will just give the new one and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I combined it with iOS' answer and it worked. Too bad I can't accept both answers or vote up since I have no reputation :(